# Left join three tables with inner join on two in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have five tables

```
tableevents

eventname eventid openingdate eventtype
alpha      2222    2019-08-07  44
beta      22299    2019-08-09  48
gama      24555    2019-06-9   47

tablesectora

eventid resultstatus liability userid  profitsectora

tablesectorb

eventid resultstatus liability userid    profitsectorb

tablesectorc

eventid resultstatus liability userid    profitsectorc

users

userid registrar_id 
io      manager
co      manager
```

what I am looking is following thing for regsitar_id suppose (manager)

> 1-show data in manager dashboard if any userid (whose registar id is
>   manager) has data in one of three or in two or in all tables tablesectora,tablesectorb and
>   tablesectorc (three table can have same eventid and cannot have same
>   eventid) 2- also show the eventname and ,eventid and opening date

`SELECT distinct tl.eventid eventid ,ul.resultstatus` `resultstatus,ce.eventname eventname,ce.opendate opendate,ce.eventtypeid` `eventtypeid ,u.registrar_id from users u, tablesectora tl left join tablesectorb uf on` `uf.eventid=tl.eventid left join tablesectorc ul  on ul.eventid=tl.eventid` `left join tableevents ce on ce.eventid=ul.eventid and u.userid=tl.userid and where u.registar_id='manager'`

The query is working but I am not able to get the expected output

> EXpected output should be

if only tablesectora has data

tablesectora

```
eventid resultstatus liability userid  profitsectora 
2222       complted   2000      io       20000
```

> Output

```
eventname eventid openingdate resultstatus  eventtype
alpha      2222    2019-08-07  completed     44
```

if tablesectora and b both have  data

tablesectora

```
eventid resultstatus liability userid  profitsectora 
2222       complted   2000      io       20000
```

tablesectorb

```
eventid resultstatus liability userid  profitsectorb
2222       complted   200000     io       200000 
22299      completed  555666     co       56666
```

> Output

```
eventname eventid openingdate resultstatus  eventtype
alpha      2222    2019-08-07  completed     44
beta       22299   2019-08-09   completed    48
```

> so you see I just want theaccumulated eventid ,eventname ,eventtype
>   and ,resultstatus (resultstatus will be same for evenry eventid in
>   every table

Comment: One thing I don't understand is `resultstatus`. All three tables have a `resultstatus` and you want to show the `resultstatus` in your results. But with multiple rows, you can get various `resultstatus`. If table A shows `resultstatus 'Completed'` and table B shows `resultstatus 'Incomplete'`, what shall be shown in the results? Or are you looking at rows with ``resultstatus = 'Completed'`?

Comment: No,thats not the case if the eventid is same then resultstatus will be same in all three tables @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Okay. That sounds like a bad data model, but it makes it easy. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter in which of the three sector tables an event occurs. So you can treat the tables as one by gluing them together with `UNION ALL`. (To me it even looks like a bad data model, and you should rather have one table with a sector type column instead of one table per sector.)

Glue the three tables' rows together, limit to managers, aggregate over event ID and join.

```
select e.eventname, e.eventid, e.openingdate, e.eventtype, s.resultstatus
from tableevents e
join
(
  select eventid, max(resultstatus) as resultstatus
  from
  (
    select eventid, resultstatus, userid from tablesectora
    union all
    select eventid, resultstatus, userid from tablesectorb
    union all
    select eventid, resultstatus, userid from tablesectorc
  ) glued
  where userid in (select userid from users where registrar_id = 'manager')
  group by eventid
) s on s.eventid = e.eventid
order by e.eventid;
```

Comment: It is throwing error ,`error in sql syntax near "manager") group by` :(

Comment: The error message is strange. First of all it should read `'manager'`, not `"manager"`, as we are dealing with a string literal here. Then, I was missing an alias for the sub query, which is obligatory. But the error message should have been `"Every derived table must have its own alias"` then. Anyway, I've added an alias. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DISTINCT on a SUBQUERY with a UNION statement to achieve this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT eventname
      ,eventid 
      ,openingdate 
      ,resultstatus  
      ,eventtype
FROM (SELECT eventname
          ,A.eventid 
          ,openingdate 
          ,resultstatus  
          ,eventtype
        FROM  tableevents A
        INNER JOIN tablescorea B
        ON    A.eventid = B.eventid
        INNER JOIN users C
        ON C.userid = A.userid
      UNION SELECT DISTINCT eventname
          ,A.eventid 
          ,openingdate 
          ,resultstatus  
          ,eventtype
      FROM  tableevents A
      INNER JOIN tablescoreb B
      ON    A.eventid = B.eventid
      INNER JOIN users C
        ON C.userid = A.userid
      )
```

Comment: but i want to join the users table as well ,for passing registarid as manager.

Comment: @ron I've added the users table, it would not change the logic